# Using Castor for Single Value classes

Tags: xml, xml-serialization, castor

I have some XML to ingest that is set up like this

```
<project>
    <client>Some client</client>
    <description>some description</description>
</project>
```

The Objects I need to unmarshal this data to are Project and Client. How do I set up my castor mapping for this?

```
<class name="Project">
  <field name="description" type="string" />
  <field name="client" type="Client" />
</class>
```

If I used the above, and I have a constructor that takes a string, will I need to also doa  mapping for the Client class - if so, what will that need to look like?

Answer (score 0):

It's quite possible that the Castor defaults - using introspection to get the list of fields with getter/setter methods, and generating XML tags based on class and member names, will do most of what you want. However you'll find you'll probably end up needing to tweak it to make sure of things like the order of the tags in the output, and the precise formatting.

The important items you'll need to add are `map-to` XML definitions for each class (which allows each XML node to be unmarshalled to the right class) and `bind-xml` nodes for each field, to allow fields to be mapped to the correct location. There's one additional change you'll make for the `client` field - you'll notice the field value in the incoming data for the client appears not as a child of the `client` node but as a child of the `project` node. You can do this by specifying `container="true"`, which means a class won't be mapped, just its fields.

(Untested) something like this, assuming the client string you have is going into a field called `name`.

```
<class name="Project">
 <map-to xml="project"/>
 <field name="client" type="Client" container="true"/>
 <field name="description" type="string"><bind-xml name="description"/></field>
</class>
<class name="Client">
 <field name="name" type="string"><bind-xml name="client"/></field>
</class>
```